# file_put_contents - contain custom variables

Tags: javascript, php, html

At the moment if I run this script, it creates the html page as expected, although I'm having trouble, having it take in to account variables, for instance the $_GET request for example.

This is inside speech marks, and is sent to a new page on my website using file_put_contents, my aim is to have the variable code defined on the page where it's sent from.

In short; at page A I have the code that creates the new file, at page A I could do something like */directory/to/page/?SET=Hello+ from+stack* and it would create the new file, and where it says  *var code = ' ';* I want it to instead be the get request, so it would be  *var code = 'Hello from stack';*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script> var code = '<?php echo $php_variable; ?>';</script>
  // This is what I'm having trouble with,
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
  <pre class='code-sample'>
    <div class='heading'>CODE</div>
    <div class='code-wrap'>
      <code></code>
    </div>
  </pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I use to create the file;

```
$file = 'it.html';
$data = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script> var code = 'I WANT THIS TO BE THE VARIABLE $GET I DEFINED FROM PAGE A';</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
  <pre class='code-sample'>
    <div class='heading'>CODE</div>
    <div class='code-wrap'>
      <code></code>
    </div>
  </pre>
</div>
";

file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: `file_put_contents()` is not like `printf()`. It doesn't feature any custom variable substitution. You just compose the string as you want it and feed it with that. You can learn more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `$GET['SET']` containing a string then all you have to remember is that when using arrays in a double quoted string you either reference the array as

```
$_GET[SET]      // without the quotes around the index name
```

Or

```
{$_GET['SET']}  // wrap the array in {}, this is my preference
```

So this should do what you want

```
$_GET['SET'] = 'Hello from stack';     // just here for testing

$file = 'it.html';
$data = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script> var code = '{$_GET['SET']}';</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
  <pre class='code-sample'>
    <div class='heading'>CODE</div>
    <div class='code-wrap'>
      <code></code>
    </div>
  </pre>
</div>
";
```

Results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script> var code = 'Hello from stack';</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
  <pre class='code-sample'>
    <div class='heading'>CODE</div>
    <div class='code-wrap'>
      <code></code>
    </div>
  </pre>
</div>
```